# Split reduced data into output and new input in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, split, mapreduce

I've been looking around for days trying to find a way using reduced data for further mapping in hadoop. I've got objects of class `A` as input data and objects of class `B` as output data. The Problem is, that while mapping not only `B`s are generated but new `A`s as well.

Here's what I'd like to achieve:

```
1.1 input: a list of As
1.2 map result: for each A a list of new As and a list of Bs is generated
1.3 reduce: filtered Bs are saved as output, filtered As are added to the map jobs

2.1 input: a list of As produced by the first map/reduce
2.2 map result: for each A a list of new As and a list of Bs is generated
2.3 ...

3.1 ...
```

You should get the basic idea.

I've read a lot about chaining but I'm not sure how to combine ChainReducer and ChainMapper or even if this would be the right approach.

So here's my question: How can I split the mapped data while reducing to save one part as output and the other part as new input data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/mapreduce/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html). As it's Javadoc suggests:

> The MultipleOutputs class simplifies writing output data to multiple
>   outputs
>
> Case one: writing to additional outputs other than the job default
>   output. Each additional output, or named output, may be configured
>   with its own OutputFormat, with its own key class and with its own
>   value class.
>
> Case two: to write data to different files provided by user

**Usage pattern for job submission:**

```
Job job = new Job();

 FileInputFormat.setInputPath(job, inDir);
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outDir);

 job.setMapperClass(MOMap.class);
 job.setReducerClass(MOReduce.class);
 ...

 // Defines additional single text based output 'text' for the job
 MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "text", TextOutputFormat.class,
 LongWritable.class, Text.class);

 // Defines additional sequence-file based output 'sequence' for the job
 MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "seq",
   SequenceFileOutputFormat.class,
   LongWritable.class, Text.class);
 ...

 job.waitForCompletion(true);
 ...
```

**Usage in Reducer:**

```
 String generateFileName(K k, V v) {
   return k.toString() + "_" + v.toString();
 }

 public class MOReduce extends
   Reducer<WritableComparable, Writable,WritableComparable, Writable> {
 private MultipleOutputs mos;
 public void setup(Context context) {
 ...
 mos = new MultipleOutputs(context);
 }

 public void reduce(WritableComparable key, Iterator<Writable> values,
 Context context)
 throws IOException {
 ...
 mos.write("text", , key, new Text("Hello"));
 mos.write("seq", LongWritable(1), new Text("Bye"), "seq_a");
 mos.write("seq", LongWritable(2), key, new Text("Chau"), "seq_b");
 mos.write(key, new Text("value"), generateFileName(key, new Text("value")));
 ...
 }

 public void cleanup(Context) throws IOException {
 mos.close();
 ...
 }

 }
```

Comment: Please note, that these code examples are for Hadoop 0.* but not 1.0.4. As I'm working with 1.0.4, the interfaces slightly changed. But the basic idea was what I've been looking for. Thank you!

Comment: yeah that's true. this was for 0.20